# A general function to display any type of struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct

I have various independent structs:

```
Struct A 
{
   type1 var1;
   type2 var2;
   type3 var3[];
   type4 var4;
};

Struct B 
{
   type5 var5;
   type6 var6;
   type7 var7;
   type8 var8;
   type9 var9[];
};
```

I want a general Display fucntion( struct general) which can take in these independent as parameter and display the fields accordingly with details in informative style not just char or byte values.

Thanks

Comment: why did you tag `C` then?

Comment: It is not possible. (but you can run your program in a debugger which will show them to you)

Comment: You will need to just declare an `operator<<` for each of them, or some other templated function. Either way, you will need to write a function for each

Comment: If you want something generic, take a look at magic_get [cppcon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abdeAew3gmQ), [github repo](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get)

Comment: `type3 var3[];` This is not a valid declaration

Comment: Or use some library which add reflexivity as boost::hana with Macro `DEFINE_STRUCT`...

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with C++ means.

Only way to generalize it is to create a support project of some kind:a parser program that would scan your header file, pick up structure definitions, and either generate code for each operator overload, or generate some kind structure definition array, in form of additional header or data file (for later use by your program). Appropriate steps must be added to make file\project file.

I was in situations where I had to implement  each of those approaches.

Third variant allows to define new structures without changing program, e.g. for parsing records in some files or network packets, where format of records changes often due to updates in different project.  Cons of such method is necessity to have dynamically identify the type of structure by its content, while first method detects type statically (in compile time).